# Dynamic Multiple dropdowns for select2 plugin

Tags: jquery-select2

I working on select2 plugin and I am need some help here.
I have a select2 dropdown and when selecting from the dropdown , I need to create another dropdown below the 1st dropdown with options excluding the one already selected. So, there will be dropdowns as many as options.

I know there is a option for Multiple, but I want like 'single block'.

Comment: Please, post the code you've tried already. Basically, you'll need to hook up to the "change" event and make a new select2 control from there

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Dethariel , I found the solution by the way.